# What happens to file descriptors when the process is killed?

Tags: files, file-descriptors

In my application I open a file, using the `open()` call.

My questions are:

- Is the file automatically closed (as using the `close()` call on the returned file descriptor) if I kill the process?
- What happens if the application crashes (e.g. segmentation fault)?
- Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the file will be automatically closed when the process terminates, regardless of the reason for the process termination.

This is [documented in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html). In “[Consequences of Process Termination](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01)”, among other consequences:

> - All of the file descriptors, directory streams, conversion descriptors, and message catalog descriptors open in the calling process shall be closed.

And in “[Terminating a Process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_08_02)”:

> It is important that the consequences of process termination as described occur regardless of whether the process called *_exit()* (perhaps indirectly through *[exit()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html)*) or instead was terminated due to a signal or for some other reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could read about Linux Kernel Process Management, e.g. [here](https://notes.shichao.io/lkd/ch3/#process-state)

> Process Termination
>
> When a process terminates, the kernel releases the resources owned by the process and notifies the child's parent of its demise.